# Import a web component only after button click

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

I am planning to show a feedback popup using web components.
Reason to use web component: Need to import it to multiple projects (Sort of a survey platform).

I need to display the web component pop up only after button click. The button will not be shown to all the users. Only to sampled users (Around 5-10%) out of which only 1% might click it. I don't want to download the web component bundle for every user but want to download only for sampled users(Especially who opt in to give feedback). As the bundle can be bigger in size as the web component app grows. Is there a way to only download the web component bundle on a button click and not for everyone

Comment: There are several ways to do this.  What does your stack look like?  Are you able to use [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import)?  Do you need to use an older module scheme like [AMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition)?

Comment: Sounds like you want a lean Client; so push HTML/CSS/JS from the Server, only for sampled users. Contact the back-end developer in your team.

Comment: Sampling is not the issue that's taken care of already. I was looking for Dynamic import which @zero298 answered. Have to try it out